# bootstrap modal disappear immediately after showing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's modal plugin in rails

The website says I can gain the function without write javascript.

I add the following line in my **HTML**(in slim):

```
div#makeDream.modal.hide.fade 
    div.modal-header
        a.close data-dismiss='modal'
        h3 Hello World!            
    div.modal-body
    div.modal-footer

a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#makeDream' Button
```

However, after I clicking the `Button`. the modal shows up, but immediately disappears!

I found the css of `#makeDream` has

```
display:none
```

I don't where it comes

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: What scripts are you including in your header?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had this problem and the solution was simple... I was loading both **bootstrap.js** AND **bootstrap-modal.js**.

**bootstrap.js** includes **bootstrap-modal.js**.

Solution: Remove **bootstrap-modal.js** from your `head` and it'll work correctly.

Comment: What happend to me is that I declared bootstrap.js on <head></head> and on below the <footer></footer> I removed the one on the <head></head>

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem of showing and immediately disappearing modal window was that I called toggle twice. First, in tag in HTML file, and then when attaching event handler in JavaScript file, like so:

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="deleteItemButton">Delete Item</a>

$ultodoListDisplay.on( "click", "#deleteItemButton",  function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

References to the Bootstrap CDN and stylesheets were correct.
Therefore, define toggle of modal window only once.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody is using twitter bootstrap modal on a mobile site, there is a big chance that you might be using jquerymobile. If so you will probably encounter this particular problem of bootstrap modal dissapearing on you. I found the problem was with a '.fadein' class from jquerymobile that was overriding the '.fadein' class from bootstrap causing the modal window to be hidden.

You can choose to fix this in your own way. My approach, since i wasn't really using fade in from jquery mobile I commented it out and Voila! the modal dialog was back. Hope this helps someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the "hide" class in this line:

```
div#makeDream.modal.hide.fade
```

To read as this:

```
div#makeDream.modal.fade
```

Also note that depending on the Bootstrap version you're using, the button to open the modal could need to be written as (translate to html slim):

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true" href="#makeDream">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: By adding the data- attributes to my <a> element it worked! I only had the boostrap.min.js file and its the latest version and I had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should add bootstrap-model.js at the bottom of webpage,
a had it problem also, I was trying with another plugin, we can use another plugin too but before use it think of bootstrap-model.js.....

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I had two references of "bootstrap.min.js", one CDN link and other local file, making comment to one of them made some dropdown menus unresponsive

then I just updated the "jQuery Validate Unobtrusive for Bootstrap 3", it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions here did not help me. I found I had used modal inside a blade form that is in laravel and that is the reason form action sends request for loop and my model disappears. I simply cut the button outside the form div and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem was with me. I removed fade class and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem , i was included both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js, then i removed one of them and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap.min.js causes this problem, removing it solves problem, 
incase it still doesn't work use

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#SendMail',function(){ 
 jQuery("#fixerrormodal").modal('toggle');   
});
```

this will help out

Answer (score 0):

In my case modals was working fine with attributes, but when called .modal('show') from js, it was hiding immediately. The problem was solved when I put bootstrap.js in footer, but I don't know why it wasn't working in header after all css and jquery declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on page load, based on the session variable, I was showing the modal, and it disappeared, when I used  $('#myModal').modal('show'), My problem got resolved by using the jquery Trigger method, on the login link I used

`$(window).load(function(){
          $('#loginlink').trigger('click');
  });`

Answer (score 0):

In my Case i was using wordpress plugin "wp-jubhunt" and "_tk" theme and both was loading bootstrap.js so disabling bootstrap.js in plugin worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a button that was calling the modal...

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" Text="Select
Action" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-backdrop="static"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalID"></asp:Button>
```

***I changed the button to an anchor tag and it works fine***

```
<a href="#" ID="btnShowModal" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"
data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal" style="width:100%;"
data-target="#myModalID">Select Action</a>
```

This was after i checked that i was not loading duplicate bootstrap javascript files. Bootstrap.min.js or boostrap.js. Just one is enough.

Comment: always try ro answer with example and description.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#myModalID"` attributes from the button or anchor tag. This toggles the modal and you have imported `bootstrap.min.`js **twice or more, which toggles it!**

Instead, write an *onClick* event listener for the button and manually trigger the modal: `$('#myModal').modal();`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. I included the correct bootstrap libraries in Layout page. then it is solved.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_bootstrap.htm

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```